# How can I get the URL of my image in Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

How can I upload image to Picasso & get a Url for it.

Generally, this code loads the image

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(mImageView);
```

How can I get the link of my image.

I didn't find the procedure in internet nor in [Picasso's page](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Please help, if anything is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "get the link of my image" ?? Dont you already have the URL : "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png" ??

Comment: Oh, I just realised that I have to upload images to a website that accepts image, and gives URL. Am i right?

Comment: Ohh This is not a uploading function or library. this loads images in your imageview from server.

Comment: OK , I have to visit a Image hosting website for making my URL. Am i right?

Comment: `How can I upload image to Picasso` - I guess you confuse Picasa (a google service) with Picasso (an image downloading library). Picasso does not upload images to Picasa.

Comment: ya, perhaps. The problem is solved . Thanks

Comment: One more Question: I am uplaoading hd images in imgur.com, so do picasso manages the resolution according in small phones, like it does from drawable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is use website like [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/). Here you can upload an image and the TinyPic website will give you a URL. Then you can display that image in your `ImageView` using the code you mentioned:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://myimage.png").into(mImageView);
```

Comment: One more Question: I am uplaoading hd images in imgur.com, so do picasso manages the resolution according in small phones, like it does from drawable?